# How to initialize Python.Runtime.dll

Tags: clr, python.net

I am trying to run OpenTD from python but I keep getting an error when importing clr.

The following error is as follows:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to initialize Python.Runtime.dll


Failed to initialize pythonnet: System.InvalidOperationException: This property must be set before runtime is initialized
    at Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)
    at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
    at Python.Runtime.Runtime.set_PythonDLL(String value)
    at Python.Runtime.Loader.Initialize(IntPtr data, Int32 size)
```

My code looks like this:

```
import sys 
import os
import clr
sys.path.append("C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/assembly/GAC_MSIL/OpenTDv63/v4.0_6.3.0.0__65e6d95ed5c2e178
clr.AddReference("OpenTDv63")
import OpenTDv63
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../'))
```

The error occurs on import clr.

I have read online that I have to call out the path such as Python.Runtime = @"My\path\to\dll" but then I get an error saying "Python" could not be found. I have installed pythonnet through anaconda if thats important.